# Rendering with RBG32UI internalFormat and reading with glReadPixels() not giving proper pixels

Tags: c++, opengl

for fun I was testing format RGB32UI for rendering.
I managed to solve problem in some fancy way, I'm curious if it's possible to do it "normally".

Here is my code to draw quad to render buffer:

```
virtual long Run()
{
    long result = NO_ERROR;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    m_program = CreateProgram(VertexShader(), "", "", "", FragmentShader());
    glLinkProgram(m_program);

    const float vertex_data[] = { -1, -1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0 };
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glUseProgram(m_program);

    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "normalizer"), 127.0);
    if (Execute<GLbyte>(GL_RGBA8I, GL_BGRA_INTEGER, GL_BYTE, 0x00, 101, 127, 85) == ERROR)
    {
        Output(2, "Fail: Internal format GL_RGBA8I\t\tType GL_BYTE.\n");
        result |= ERROR;
    }
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "normalizer"), 32767.0);
    if (Execute<GLshort>(GL_RGBA16I, GL_BGRA_INTEGER, GL_SHORT, 0x0000, 26214, 32767, 21845) == ERROR)
    {
        Output(2, "Fail: Internal format GL_RGBA16I\t\tType GL_SHORT.\n");
        result |= ERROR;
    }
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "normalizer"), 2147483647.0);
    if (Execute<GLint>(GL_RGBA32I, GL_BGRA_INTEGER, GL_INT, 0x00000000, 1717987071, 2147483647, 1431655807) == ERROR)
    {
        Output(2, "Fail: Internal format GL_RGBA32I\t\tType GL_INT.\n");
        result |= ERROR;
    }

    return result;
}

template<typename T>
long Execute(const long& internalFormat, const long& format, const long& type, const long& B, const long& G, const long& R, const long& A)
{
    long result = NO_ERROR;

    std::vector<T> dataIN(8192 * 4);
    std::vector<T> dataOUT(8192 * 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++)
    {
        dataIN[4 * i] = B;
        dataIN[4 * i + 1] = G;
        dataIN[4 * i + 2] = R;
        dataIN[4 * i + 3] = A;
    }

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, 8192, 1, 0, format, type, &dataIN[0]);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, type, &dataOUT[0]);

    if (memcmp(&dataIN[0], &dataOUT[0], sizeof(T) * 8192 * 4) != 0)
    {
        Output(3, "Texel read from bound texture (%d, %d, %d, %d) is not equal to texel wrote to bound texture (%d, %d, %d, %d).\n",
            dataOUT[0], dataOUT[1], dataOUT[2], dataOUT[3], dataIN[0], dataIN[1], dataIN[2], dataIN[3]);
        result = ERROR;
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    std::vector<vec4> pix(100 * 100);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 100, 100, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &pix[0]);
    DisplayData(100, 100, pix);

    result |= CheckRectColor(pix, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, vec4(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f, 0.666666f)) ? NO_ERROR : ERROR;

    return result;
}
```

My fancy VertexShader:

```
std::string FragmentShader()
{
    return
        CONF_SHADER_BEGIN(430)
        NL "in vec2 texCoord;"
        NL "out vec4 out_color;"
        NL "uniform isampler2D tex;"
        NL "uniform float normalizer;"
        NL "void main() {"
        NL "    ivec4 color = texture(tex, texCoord);"
        NL "    out_color = vec4(color.rgb / normalizer, color.a / normalizer);"
        NL "}";
}
```

As you can see I'd like to render texture with GL_BGRA_INTEGER type (formats: GL_RGBA8I, GL_RGBA16I, GL_RGBA32I) to buffer and then read pixels from it with glReadPixels().
I tried to do it with GL_FLOAT and GL_INT formats but they give me nothing...
Only way I managed to do it is by normalizing values inside shader.
The way I'd like to do it is with FragmentShader below:

```
virtual std::string FragmentShader()
{
    return
        CONF_SHADER_BEGIN(430)
        NL "in vec2 texCoord;"
        NL "out ivec4 out_color;"
        NL "uniform isampler2D tex;"
        NL "void main() {"
        NL "    out_color = texture(tex, texCoord);"
        NL "}";
}
```

And read pixels with:

```
std::vector<ivec4> pix(100 * 100);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 100, 100, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, &pix[0]);
```

Comment: What you actually do is to write to and read from the default frame buffer. The format of the default framebuffer is a unsigned normalized floating point format. Of course the texture contains integral data, but the format of render target is not integral. What you want to do is possible only, if you would render to a named [Framebuffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object), where the color attachment has an integral internal format.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess that answers my question.